# Codeigniter select box not populating session value

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, select

I am facing a `session` problem with Codeigniter. 
I have a form containing a select box to perform a search. When the form gets submitted, the search criteria is stored in session, which is used to populate the form fields once user gets back to the form. In my local machine, it works fine. But in server, it doesn't for select boxes. Upon clearing the browser cache only, it works.
 
I have just echoed the session variable. outside the form. And it holds the correct data.In Firebug, it shows the correct value also -  `<option selected="selected">foobar</option>`. But I can't see the selected value in the select box.
FYI - I am using the following CI form helper to print select box.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('product', $search_options['product_list'], 
      stripslashes($this->session->userdata('qes_product')), 
      'id="qes_product" tabindex="1"'); 
?>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you're using DB storage for your session and not a cookie. Cookies have a limited size, and if you're doing something wrong, meaning not replacing the values but constantly adding them to the session, then it can get full. This is something else you should look into (what you store in your session)

2) Don't use $this->session in your view. Store everything in a array (like $formdata) in your session, then retrieve it in your controller and pass it to your view.

You can access it in your form using `$formdata['ques_product']`

If above doesn't help, try changing the value of `sess_expire_on_close` in your session config. There seems to be weird a bug in CI.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I am using DB storage for sessions. I have checked server DB session table for search value and it stores it. I understand your suggestion regarding the usage of $this->session. To test, I have printed all the session values by using `$this->session->all_userdata()` in the form template. Then also, it doesn't bring it. FYI - I have given `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` even. As I have said earlier, it brings value only upon refreshing browser's cache.

Comment: How about changing `sess_expire_on_close`? If that doesn't help, what I would do is enable logging and then insert `log_message('debug', 'Somewhere'. $this->session->userdata('qes_product');` in all different places, starting with your controller, constructor and even model. This way you can see what happens to it. Good luck!